# Typescript type method with a return inside a .then()

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am currently coding a function that inserts a user into a database, and I need it to return a promise with the type of a User class I made:

```
async createUser(user: User): Promise<User> {
const userObject: User = user;
hash(userObject.password, saltRounds)
  .then(
    (pwdHash) => {
      userObject.password = pwdHash;
      return this.userRepository.insert(userObject);
    },
  )
  .catch(
    (err) => {
      // TODO: Log error
      console.log(err);
    },
  );
}
```

However, I'm running into a problem where my IDE and typescript are complaining that the function needs to return a Promise of type User, which it is, inside the .then() callback, but it doesn't seem to be understanding that, which means that I can't type the function.
Is there anything that I'm missing?

Comment: You need `return` before
`hash(userObject.password, saltRounds)`. For now your function returns nothing

Comment: Thanks a lot @Pvl!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue, I returned the whole hash function as well